# SQL statement to get joined values

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables student and attendance as follows.

```
 ID   Name
 001  Bob
 002  Jack
 003  Mary

 ID StentID  OffDays  Month  Year
 1  001       2        jan   2018
 2  002       4        feb   2018
 3  002       1        mar   2017
 4  003       2        Apr   2018
```

i want to write a query to list all students with offdays based on month and year.

i used this query but lists only the students who taken leave. it is not listing other students. :

```
select mast.Name, att.Year, att.Month, ISNULL(att.Days,0) 
from student mast left outer join
     StudentAttendance att
     on mast.ID= att.StentID
where Month = 'jan' and Year = 2018
```

I want to get a result like this :

```
Name   Month year OffDyas
Bob     jan  2018   2
Jack    jan  2018   0
Mary    jan  2018   0
```

Comment: Assuming that `month` and `year` are in the table`StudentAttendance`, referencing them like you have in your `WHERE` implicitly turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the conditions on the second table in the `on` clause not the `where` clause:

```
select s.Name, 2018 as Year, 'jan' as Month, coalesce(st.Days, 0) 
from student s left outer join
     StudentAttendance st
     on st.StentID = m.ID and st.month = 'jan' and st.year = 2018;
```

When the conditions are in the `where` clause, the `left join` turns into an `inner join`.